# Prometheus handler strange output using Gin

Tags: http, go, prometheus, go-gin

Basically, I'm developing an HTTP endpoint to get the metrics from prometheus package.
Following the instructions in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/65609042/17150602] I created a handler to be able to call promhttp.Handler() like so:

```
g.GET("/metrics", prometheusHandler())

func prometheusHandler() gin.HandlerFunc {
        h := promhttp.Handler()
        return func(c *gin.Context) {
            h.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
        }
    }
```

The thing is, when I call `localhost:1080/metrics` the output shows like this (**btw, I'm using Postman**):

[Postman request to get metrics with wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAR0O.png)

But if, for instance, I change the port and use http instead of gin package like so:

```
http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
http.ListenAndServe(promAddr, nil)
```

The output shows OK as you can see here:

[Postman reuest to get metrics with correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sFdg.png)

What and why is this happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to remove a compression middleware like gzip.